# How can I add fonts to my Android phone to view characters that are appearing as X boxes?

Tags: fonts

I am frustrated with the apparent inability to figure out which charset or language I need to install to view characters that appear as "X"s on my Samsung GS6 phone.  I am running Android 7.0.  Non-rooted phone.

For example:  On Twitter, when I use the app on my phone, someone's name appears entirely in Xs.  I assumed it was a multichar language like Korean or Japanese (both of which I have installed) but it turns out it's just bold face Roman.  (Which I see when I pull up the user via Twitter's web interface on my computer.)

Other times, I am sure it's an emoticon or such that someone sends that doesn't show properly.

How can I know which languages or icon sets to install so I can view these?

(Note, my computer, a Lubuntu machine, usually displays things fine.  So this is a phone question.)

Thank you so much for helping with this.  Driving me nuts.